# .jsp shows as plain text after migrating from TOMCAT 6.0 to 7.0

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6

I am trying to migrate a project from TOMCAT 6.0.33 to 7.0.54.

After some trouble, I was able to run the server without errors or warning. 
But when I tried to acces the previously funtional pages, the content of the jsp itself shows as plain text, like so :

```
<%@page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
etc....
```

The .war is build using JDK 1.8 and as I said before, it is fully functional in a TOMCAT 6.0 server. 
I've been trying to find similar issues or solution without luck so far.

Thank you for your time

Comment: any error in the logs?

Comment: So take a step back and let go of this application for a second. Create a new simple war with a single JSP in it with some really basic hello world line and see if that works first. Don't copy stuff from the application which isn't working, find a fresh resource online and follow it to produce a completely new application. It should take almost no effort. If it works: it's something in the application and you need to provide more information. If it doesn't, someone or something broke the server configuration.

Comment: @mumpitz :
Sorry i forgot to mention that, there is no error or warning in the logs, nor when the server is started, nor when the .jsp are display via their usual URL

Comment: @Gimby :
Thank you for your advice, I am very new in this matter. I did deploy a "Hello World!" project with a simple JSP and it's own pom. It does work, which means the problem shouldn't come from the TOMCAT configuration.

I am currently checking the maven modules compatibility with TOMCAT 7.